# Where is the information in python sets and dicts stored?

Tags: python, dictionary, memory, set, size

When placing elements of absurdly different sizes in a python set (or dict), the size of the set/dict is the same. Where is the information stored and how do I find its size?

```
import sys

s1 = ""
for x in range(100000):
    s1 += str(x)

long_key_set = set()
short_key_set = set()

for i in range(10):
    # Adding a small value
    short_key_set.add(i)

    # Adding a large value
    s = s1 + str(i)
    long_key_set.add(s)

print(sys.getsizeof(long_key_set))
print(sys.getsizeof(short_key_set))
```

Comment: The [documentation for `getsizeof()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) explicitly says: "Only the memory consumption directly attributed to the object is accounted for, not the memory consumption of objects it refers to." and then has a link to a way to calculate the size of the object + contents.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the smallest size of a dictionary/set is **8**.if you are only storing **three** values, Python will still allocate eight elements. On resize, the number of buckets increases by **4x** until we reach **50,000** elements, after which the size is increased by **2x**. This gives the following possible sizes
8, 32, 128, 512, **2048**, 8192, 32768, 131072, 262144, ...